# Best antenna design with the following requirements?

Tags: antenna, radio, wifi, antenna-array, lte

I'm looking for the best antenna design with the following requirements

- Small
- Discrete
- Wideband (LTE and WiFi)
- Directional
- High gain (20-25dBi with relatively high transmission power)

Could anyone help me determine what the best design would be for such an antenna?

I've thought about using the following designs already.

- Parabolic, too big not discrete
- Yagi-Uda, too big not discrete, narrow band
- LPDA, suited but hard to find with a high gain, not to sure about the range
- Helical, hard to find with high gain, not sure about the range, narrow band

Are there really no small antenna's out there who have a wideband and are still able to have a high gain?

Comment: As an antenna rule of thumb, your requirements of "electrically small", "broadband", and "highly directional" are usually considered mutually exclusive. So the simple answer is "no".  But try being more specific: what size? what do you mean by discrete? how wideband (% frequency coverage)?

Comment: In an ideal situation a similar size to how a regular helical antenna looks that you'd use with your router for example something like this http://www.annxin.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/269/2018/04/5dBi-GSM-Antenna-10-300x300.jpg the size may be bigger or smaller as long as it's not incredibly big (I.E parabolic dishes, 60cm Yagi-Uda's...).

By discrete I mean something which doesn't scream that it's a high gain antenna (I.E parabolic dishes, 60cm Yagi-Uda's...) like a small helical antenna you normally see on routers yet with a bunch of higher gain or maybe like a panel antenna such as

Comment: https://3i2kbu3p64zdryox2qp5q43na-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/simplewifi-8dbi-directional-mini-panel-antenna-VB5A0556a-510x347.jpg